# How can I "clear" an entire website

Tags: install

I'm selling the same website build in Craft to multiple clients and was wondering if it is possible to clear all user generated content of an install.

So delete all the entries, categories, assets, globals, ...

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this using a tool like schematic https://github.com/nerds-and-company/schematic

This allows you to generate all your fields and sections from a file without content. Combine this with a migration to seed dummy data (if you need that)

However, craft 3.1 will ship with a [Project config](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/3.1/docs/project-config.md) which will do the same thing.

Comment: I have a similar situation, and I’ve found that the new project.yaml file which comes with Craft 3.1 works well to accomplish the task. I created a “prototype” website with all the sections, fields, settings and base templates - but with no content. I just duplicate the repo, connect it to a duplicated DB and voila.